# Attribute error with MySQL's connection object

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am *trying* to use this script to create a connection and search with MySQL database.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb as msd
import json
class Test_oop():
    host = "localhost"
    user = "root"
    password = "123456"
    database = "test_1"

    def __init__(self):
        self.dbs = None

    def create_connection(self):
        self.dbs = msd.connect(self.host,self.user,self.password, self.database)

    def close_connection():
        self.dbs.close()

    def search(self, name):
        cursor = self.dbs
        print type(cursor)
        cursor.execute("SELECT adress FROM phoneID WHERE Name = %s", (name))
        return cursor.fetchall()
```

But when i try to run it, I get the following error:

```
>>> from test_oop import Test_oop as top
>>> search_query = top()
>>> search_query.create_connection()
>>> search_query.search('Tommy')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test_oop.py", line 42, in search
    cursor.execute("SELECT adress FROM phoneID WHERE Name = %s", (name))
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

I did a `type()`on `cursor` after `cursor=self.dbs`in `search()` method
and i found that `cursor` is a `<class 'MySQLdb.connections.Connection'>`

I am not sure what am I missing?

Comment: Try `cursor = self.dbs.cursor()`

Comment: @vaultah thanks! it worked. 
PS: if i had a update method like http://pastie.org/pastes/10612972/text , i would use `self.dbs.commit()` to commit changes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @vaultah in comments, this solved my problem:
`cursor = self.dbs.cursor()`
I was not initiating the cursor() function and that's why i facing the `AttributeError`

For committing the changes: `self.dbs.commit()`